# svelte: how can a component modify a variable/object on its parent?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

I have a main application that contains the user object and the login component

```
<script>
let user = {}
</script>

hello {user.username}
<login user={user} />
```

In the login component, I make a call to ajax and receive some data like:

```
user = {id:1, username:"john"}
```

How can I then  "inform" the main application I have updated the user so it displays hello john

For now, I dispatch an event

```
import { createEventDispatcher } from 'svelte';
const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();
```

Is there a better way to achieve that ?

Comment: Why not create a login svelte store to observe and share the login state.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In Svelte you can bind values to a component, so that when the child component updates, it also updates the parent.

You just need to change

```
<login user={user} />
```

to

```
<login bind:user={user} />
```

Here's a [demo](https://svelte.dev/repl/c0281711b74742a3b633f4ef005861af?version=3.24.0)

Answer (score 6):

Svelte has 2-way binding via the `bind` keyword. You may have seen it when binding form inputs, and it works the same way in your own parent-child relationships.

Here's how it looks: `<Login bind:user={user} />` or the shorthand when the names are the same: `<Login bind:user />`.

All you have to do is define a prop in the child (Login) component and when you update it, the parent value changes.

[Here is a REPL to see it in action](https://svelte.dev/repl/41b3ac3042434f1691dd9f4ff56eb89b?version=3.24.0)

---

Some extra things I'll point out in case you're interested:

1. Components usually start with a capital letter. This allows the compiler to differentiate them with regular HTML components. Who knows, someday there may be an HTML component named `<login>`!
2. While the strategy above works for user logins, the typical way to handle this is using the concept of [stores](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/writable-stores).

Answer (score 3):

I think there are 3 ways to solve this:

**localstore:**

- create a store and subscribe to it in your app. e.g.: https://svelte.dev/tutorial/writable-stores

**dispatching:**

- as you are doing currently ;)

**two-way-binding:**

- e.g.: https://svelte.dev/tutorial/text-inputs

Comment: And which one do you think is the "cleanest"?

Comment: I would implement a storage solution. Thinking on OIDC token flow or session related information this might be useful?

Comment: If there is no need, dispatching is fine for me. Mentioning that two-way-binding is good for frequently changing values, the login process is used only once per session.

Comment: otherwise: less code is always better! -> two-way-binding??? It depends;) best